# How to test session timeout in php?

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

Why doesn't this code work?

```
session_start();

// 5 mins in seconds
$inactive = 300; 
$session_life = time() - $_session['timeout'];
if($session_life > $inactive)
{  
    session_destroy(); header("Location: client_login.php");     
} 
else 
{
    $_session['timeout']=time();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `var_dump( $_session );` after your if/else statement and see if `$_session['timeout']` is set or has a value.  following `session_destroy()` the session should be empty.

**update**

Try changing `$_session` to `$_SESSION`.  This is a special PHP variable and case may matter

Comment: i've put the var_dump ($_session); but it's still not working? and what do you mean by "see if $_session['timeout'] is set or has a value."? i'm sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: following the first run you should have a session variable 'timeout' which contains a value.  Once you reach the limit set by the $inactive variable the session_destroy should empty the session thus removing the timeout variable from the session.  Also see my answer again for an update.

Comment: i'm sorry but it's still not working. i've add the timeout value but there's nothing. and it supposed to direct me to client_login.php page right if the session is destroyed? is it possible it's not working because i misplaced the code?

Answer (score -1):

Check :

`print_r($_SESSION)`  and  `print_r($_SESSION['timeout'])`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.